# Redisearch equivalent for a MySQL query

Tags: redis, redisearch

I'm looking for the **Redisearch** equivalent of the following query:

```
NOT (topic_id = '123' AND post_id <= '456')
```

I tried the following - it works but doesn't look like the most elegant solution:

```
-(@topic_id:[123 123] @post_id:[-inf 456])
```

`topic_id` and `post_id` are **NUMERIC** and **SORTABLE**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Chris,
Your query looks perfectly valid, the only simplification I would apply is:

```
-(@topic_id:123 @post_id:[-inf 456])
```

To avoid repeating the `123` value. The other option would be to use DeMorgan's law and rewrite your `NOT(A AND B)` to `(!A OR !B)` but I don't think that would buy you anything, and in this case it would make it harder to read I think.

Comment: Ok so if topic_id is NUMERIC I can do @topic_id:123 and it won't find 1234 etc.? Thanks for your help!